# Is the $1 per day visa for Peru real?

Tags: visas, peru

I originally planned to be in Peru for less than 60 days (which is the length of the visa given to me) but now I would like to stay longer, for 90 days. After calling the peruvian office they told me that everything would be fine as long as I paid $1 per day of time spent extra in the country.

Does anybody have any experience with this? I find this claim, even though it comes from an official, a little bit odd.

Comment: Are you on tourist visa? From your profile I assume you are Dutch citizen - and as such you should not need a visa if you stay up to 90 days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 1 USD is not a fee, it's [a fine you have to pay](http://www.expatperu.com/etourist.php) when overstaying your visa. There does not seem to be a possibility to extend the visa, once you are in Peru, but if you have the chance to [leave Peru somewhere for a day](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/tourist-visa-peru-56148.html) and come back, you might be able to stay longer - specially as a tourist.

If you are a resident citizen of the Netherlands, you should be able to get a 183 days visa on arrival for tourism. If you work there, this is a different issue however.

Answer (score 4):

30 days is no problem, i was over by a year a few years back and just paid the fine right at the airport. i'm over again now . . . by 2 years :( - no worries. you hand your plane ticket over like normal, they look at you nervously and explain that you'll have to pay, you say cool and they'll send you to a different line and pay.

if you leave peru by bus it's as big problem. the bus stops at the border everyone gets thru except you. there is no infrastructure in place to resolve the problem. bus driver threatens to leave you, the passengers get pissed, you beg someone to take your money but they don't know what to do.